# RNO's are assigned completely different when running the outer query when using the ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY

Tags: sql-server-2012

```
SELECT  KID,SSN,SID,YEAR,FNAME,LNAME,DOB, GENDER, RACE 
    FROM 
    ( SELECT  KID,SSN, SID,YEAR,FNAME,LNAME,DOB, GENDER, RACE,ROW_NUMBER()  OVER(PARTITION BY FNAME,LNAME,DOB
            ORDER BY year DESC ) RNO    
            from #t17
        )A
            WHERE RNO=1
```

I am doing Partition on FNAME,LNAME,DOB and I need to get the most recent year record of each person so I am doing order by 'YEAR' column, when I just run the inner query the RNO's are assigned correctly for each record but when I run the outer query, if you can see the outer select and I have kept a condition where RNO=1 then I am getting different records.
Issue is with the outer query when I run the outer query the RNO's are changing completely and I also tried of keeping inner query in a temp table and then thought of filtering the RNO that is also showing different RNO's if I do so. 
I have also tried using CTE that is also showing an issue with the RNO when I run the outer query. Please let me know if there is any alternative

Comment: Wouldn't a person be better identified by a unique ID, like SSN, or some other ID (maybe SID)? Instead of a combination of FNAME+LNAME+DOB to uniquely identify the person?

Comment: Could you also give us some sample data to show the row numbers generated? PLEASE DEPERSONALIZE THE DATA BEFORE SHARING! (Sorry for shouting, but given some of the data there is SSN info, it's warranted!)